# Schedule E (rents) — which line for cost of permits?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, schedule-e

I have recently bought rental property. I am required to (and did) register the property with the city. It's not an ad valorem tax; it's a flat fee per unit.

Is there any more appropriate line on Schedule E Expenses than "Other"?